# jquery: Why must the trigger for a .click() be inside of a link?

Tags: jquery

I have a Problem with .click() on my page.
I want to execute this:

```
$('.projLink').click(function() {
    $('#project').addClass('projSide');
    $('#wrapper').addClass('wrapSide');
    $('nav').addClass('navSide');
});
```

And the html looks like this:

```
<li><span class="projLink">Bone</span></li>
```

Now sadly this doesn't work. I have to put the trigger inside a link in order to make it work:

```
<li><a href="#project"><span class="projLink">Bone</span></a></li>
```

I have used .click() in other parts of the page and it works without link tags. Here is my test page:
http://www.henning-marxen.de/test/ The first item in the portfolio has a link, the others don't. Do you know why jquery behaves like this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Now sadly this doesn't work."* Yes, it does. Example: http://jsbin.com/muradopa/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/muradopa/1/edit). If you put together a [self-contained, complete replicating example](http://sscce.org) and put it **in** the question (not just linked like your test page; links rot, and people shouldn't have to leave the site to help you), we can help you figure out why it's not working *for you*.

Comment: Can you replicate in jsfiddle? Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/3t9Yc/

Comment: I know that it should work. It just doesn't on my page and I have no Idea why.

Comment: @H.Marxen: Start with a working fiddle (like Curt's) and then add parts from your original page until it stops working.

Comment: It's working http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/3t9Yc/1/

Comment: My guess is that you haven't included jQuery and that you're getting errors in the console that you probably haven't looked at.

Comment: I put a debugger in the trigger function. It seems to be triggering for all the required elements. Check if the required classes are being updated properly for the slide to work.
Edited (Reason: typo)

Answer (score 1):

The code that sets the class to start the animation works fine, but then the click bubbles to the parent element where it triggers the code that removes the classes to move it back. Use the `stopPropagation` method to keep the click event from bubbling:

```
$('.projLink').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#project').addClass('projSide');
    $('#wrapper').addClass('wrapSide');
    $('nav').addClass('navSide');
});
```

Comment: THAT WORKS! :) Thank you very much. This goes far beyond my expertise of throwing a few animations in there.^^